# Detect scroll wheel signal in system tray using Python AppIndicator in Ubuntu 12.04

Tags: python, scroll, appindicator

I'm trying to get this python code to react when the mouse hovers over the tray icon and scrolls the mouse wheel, I can't find any examples online.  This is what I have so far, it doesn't react to scrolling the wheel...

```
#!/usr/bin/python

APPNAME = "My App"
ICON = "/usr/share/pixmaps/firefox.png"

import appindicator as AI
import gtk


def sayhello(item):
    print "menu item selected"


def scroll(aai, ind, steps):
    print "hello"  # doesn't print anything


def makemenu():
    ' Set up the menu '
    menu = gtk.Menu()
    check = gtk.MenuItem('Check')
    exit = gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
    check.connect('activate', sayhello)
    exit.connect('activate', gtk.main_quit)
    menu.append(check)
    menu.append(exit)
    return menu


def startapp():
    ai = AI.Indicator(APPNAME, ICON, AI.CATEGORY_APPLICATION_STATUS)
    ai.set_status(AI.STATUS_ACTIVE)
    ai.connect("scroll-event", scroll)
    ai.set_menu(makemenu())
    gtk.main()

startapp()
```

How can I detect scroll wheel movements?

Comment: Thanks for testing, you are right, it does work, I have just tested with gnome-panel and it works fine.  I was previously using the Notification Area in Cairo/GLX dock, must be a bug in that.  If you want to submit your comment as the answer I will mark it as the accepted answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

That is the correct way to connect to the mouse scroll event and the code does work, tested on two 12.04 systems. There might be a bug however as the first few test runs on one of them did not work either but then was fine.

If you are starting from scratch I would recommend using pygobject (Gtk3) instead of pygtk (Gtk2) as it is no longer developed. As part of testing I did convert your script to pygobject and fixed showing the menu:

```
#!/usr/bin/env python

APPNAME = "My App"
ICON = "/usr/share/pixmaps/firefox.png"

from gi.repository import AppIndicator3 as AI
from gi.repository import Gtk

def sayhello(item):
    print "menu item selected"

def scroll(aai, ind, steps):
    print "hello" # doesn't print anything

def makemenu():
    ' Set up the menu '
    menu = Gtk.Menu()
    check_item = Gtk.MenuItem('Check')
    exit_item = Gtk.MenuItem('Quit')
    check_item.connect('activate', sayhello)
    check_item.show()
    exit_item.connect('activate', Gtk.main_quit)
    exit_item.show()
    menu.append(check_item)
    menu.append(exit_item)
    menu.show()
    return menu

def startapp():
    ai = AI.Indicator.new(APPNAME, ICON, AI.IndicatorCategory.HARDWARE)
    ai.set_status(AI.IndicatorStatus.ACTIVE)
    ai.set_menu(makemenu())
    ai.connect("scroll-event", scroll)
    Gtk.main()

startapp()
```

Comment: Thanks again! And thanks for the pygobject example.  I have tested your example and again it works fine in gnome-panel but Cairo Dock 3.2.1 seems oblivious to scroll wheel movement.

Comment: Just a note, I'm using XUbuntu and replacing scroll(aai, ind, steps) with scroll(aai=None, ind=None, steps=None) makes it work (kind of).